# Ubuntu 14.04 biblatex

Tags: latex

maybe I just did not get any information while searching through google pages but I really tried to find some about biblatex.

I tried `aptitude search biblatex` but nothing appeared.

Why isn't biblatex in the Universe anymore? Is there some other/newer software to replace biblatex in 14.04?

thanks for every answer :)

ascenator

Answer (score 48, accepted):

From the [launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+source/biblatex/1.7-1) of `biblatex in 14.04` You can see that

```
 1.7-1
DELETED: Trusty pocket Release in component universe and section tex

    Removal requested on 2013-10-24.
    Deleted on 2013-10-24 by Colin Watson

    (From Debian) ROM; included in TeX Live, no need for separate packaging;
```

It has been removed as a seperate package and has been included in `texlive`, specifically the `texlive-bibtex-extra` package. So just install that package as follows:

```
 sudo apt-get install texlive-bibtex-extra
```

You may also want biber, in which case instead run:

```
 sudo apt-get install texlive-bibtex-extra biber
```